# Php SQL Injection statement using Session Data tags

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to insert $_SESSION data and htmlentities($dnn into a database for a friend requests table, current SQL injection is as follows -

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO friend_requests (sender, recipient, status)
VALUES ('"$_SESSION["user"]["id"]"', '4', '2')";
```

It's most likely something very simple, although I'm kinda a noob with speech marks in php.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `htmlentities` your sentence seems cut off. You should use prepared statements though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Yep, usually I have it disabled. But removed the disabled tag and was surprised no errors showed up. And even the fact actually no html code was even shown on the page, non of the head code. Not even the correct page title.

Comment: Your error reporting settings must be off. You need to concatenate or use curly braces to bring the variable into your query... You should use prepared statements still though.

Comment: Actually I think your right, they could be off default by apache - Migrated to a host the other day and would have thought they may be on by default as my previous Wamp Apache had -
I've also tried prepared statements using - $UsrID = "'$_SESSION["user"]["id"]'" VALUES ('$UsrID', '4', '2')"; Although that could be terribly wrong

Comment: What driver are you using? Can you post your full code?

Comment: *"I've also tried prepared statements using - $UsrID = "'$_SESSION["user"]["id"]'" VALUES ('$UsrID', '4', '2')";"* - That isn't a prepared statement. Plus, we have no idea what MySQL API you're using to connect with. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO?

Comment: That => http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements is prepared statements in PDO. Show your full code. Not in comments, in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this without the double quotes for the sender value

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO friend_requests (sender, recipient, status)
VALUES ($_SESSION["user"]["id"], '4', '2')";
```

Comment: If he/she is talking about preventing injections prepared statements are the way to go. You have no idea what is in `$_SESSION["user"]["id"]` this could be dangerous.

Comment: Tried that didn't work unfortianly, although the $_SESSION["user"]["id"] didn't have the usual syntax highlighting. The htmlentities is for the ID of the recipient, and the Session ID is the id of the user adding the recipient.

Comment: I've also tried prepared statements using -
$UsrID = "'$_SESSION["user"]["id"]'"
VALUES ('$UsrID', '4', '2')";
Although that could be terribly wrong